# Como carregar script e ccs externo em uma url blob javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quero usar paginas temporarias com o `blob` mas não está carregando os arquivos externos, é possível fazer isso com o `blob`? Se não, teria outra maneira de fazer paginas temporárias sem cria-las no servidor, apenas do lado do cliente?
https://codepen.io/markvaaz/pen/ZEEbvMz

```js
function urlBlob(text){
  var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "HTML"});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.innerHTML = "Clica"
  document.body.appendChild(a)
}
urlBlob(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://app.sollic.com/style-1.0.9.css">
<div class="prealfa">Alguma coisa aqui</div>
<script src="https://app.sollic.com/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: O wordpress armazena as informações das páginas no banco de dados e somente as renderiza para o cliente. Acredito que dê para fazer com texto simples mesmo. Mas aí, deve ficar atento a ataques maliciosos.

Comment: A questão servidor e banco de dados está fora de cogitação, a solução que estou procurando é apenas no lado do cliente.

Comment: Como as informações serão criadas para que, depois, elas sejam exibidas para o cliente?

Comment: Como vc pode ver no exemplo do codepen, o codigo vai pegar elementos HTML, ocultos ou não, e criar uma url blob para acessar esses elementos temporariamente, porém 100% dos scripts são carregados através de fonte externa, no blob aparentemente não carrega de fonte externa...
(Não tem a ver com segurança, se o usuário tiver conhecimento ele pode acessar esses elementos ocultos como quiser).